# CSVHelper - No Output

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am trying to create a csv file using the `CSVHelper` nuGet package

This is the code

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    var sr = new StreamWriter(ms);
    var csv = new CsvWriter(sr);

    csv.WriteField("sd");
    csv.WriteField("sd");
    csv.WriteField("sd");
    csv.WriteField("sd");

    //ms.Seek(0, 0);
    sr.Flush();
    //ms.Position = 0;
    var len = ms.Length;

    return File(ms, "text/csv", "test.csv");
}
```

However, the file is always blank

I have read several questions on here that suggest the `StreamWriter` needs to be flushed. The position moved to 0. However, Ive tried that and it doesnt seem to work

I have also tried the same with `using` statements for the `MemoryStream`, `StreamWriter` and `CSVWriter`
I've tried all of these and it is still blank

Whatsmore, the length of the `MemoryStream` is always zero

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code does not even compile ... ?

Comment: presume you either haven't referenced the csvhelper dll or dont have the mvc references

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out - I needed to pass a byte array, instead of a stream, to the FileContentResult :

```
return File(ms.ToArray(), "text/csv", "test.csv");
```

Comment: if its stream or ToArray conversion does not have directly something to do with the CsvWriter - In some circumstances I noted that the CsvWriter is zero (empty)

Answer (score 2):

Whenver CsvHelper has no output the most common reason for this is, that the writer need a `sw.Flush()`

Using CsvWriter without configuration perfectly worked

```
CsvWriter(sw); // with no configuration
```

By using the configuration `IgnoreReferences = true` I came up with an empty csv

```
CsvWriter(sw, new Configuration.CsvConfiguration() {
    Delimiter = ";", 
    IgnoreReferences = true
});
```

**The Solution (complete example)**

```
var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms);
var csvOut = new CsvWriter(sw, new Configuration.CsvConfiguration() { Delimiter = ";", IgnoreReferences = true });

csvOut.WriteRecords(someCollection);

// IMPORTANT LINE
sw.Flush();

ms.Position = 0;
return File(ms, "text/csv", "resultFile.csv");
```

Hint found on Github: https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/47

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you write end of record when you are using WriteField method `writer.NextRecord();`
to write a data to csv file you can use the code bellow:

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"test.csv"))
        {
            var writer = new CsvWriter(sw);
            writer.WriteField("Fist field");
            writer.NextRecord();
            writer.WriteField("Second field");
            writer.NextRecord();
            //add what you wana here
        }
```